# When can I Taylor expand a function of an operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

1-) Is the expression

$f(A) = \sum_n \frac{f'(0)}{n!}(A)^n$

always meaningful for any diagonalizable linear operator $A$ and for any analytic function $f$? This seems strange to me because then I could express any non-linear differential operator $f(A)$ in terms of the linear ones $A$ and then solve easily any non-linear differential equation.

2-) Is this problem related to the fact that differential operators are not bounded?

3-) What are the specific conditions that makes the above equation true? I would say that the expansion only makes sense when $f(A)$ is applied to the eigenvectors $v$ of $A$, which in turn would mean that

$f(A)v_n=f(\lambda_n)v_n$.

This seems to make sense since we can define $f(A)$ for diagonalizable $A$ as being the matrix/operator whose diagonal is $f(\lambda_n)$. Is it right?

Comment: $A$ have to be bounded in order for the series to converge

Comment: So if $A$ is bounded I can always taylor expand $f(A)$?

Comment: $A$ need not be diagonalizable. For every bounded operator $A$ on a complex Banach space your definition of $f(A)$ makes sense for entire functions. It is again a bounded linear operator, and one has many desirable properties, e.g., $(g\circ f)(A)=g(f(A))$.

Comment: @Jochen could you give me some reference on this? Thanks.

Comment: Look at *Holomorphic functional calculus*.